# failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I am making multiple calls to server on exit of the app and also on start of the app, based on a timestamp. Basically I pull and push data.

**I am making asynchronous calls to server**

But what is happening is that I am getting this message in debug console

> void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate
>   (webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener:)
>   failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode:
>   kCFRunLoopDefaultMode

My app hangs. I am not understanding what is going wrong.

Regards
Ranjit.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: what code you need? I mean making of serve calls? Or parsing of json data

Comment: Yes, I presume it doesn't run asynchronously.

Comment: It does, I am using the delegate methods, which get me response.

Answer (score 1):

Try to split work to 2 pieces. A background task which runs async and the part which should run in main queue.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

  // do things which can run in background
  // calculations-delay-waiting for a response etc.

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: {

    // implement UI related part which has to run in main thread.

  })
}
```